# folderbrowserdialog selectedpath returns no value

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderfinder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    folderfinder.Description = "Select Folder";
    folderfinder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    folderfinder.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

    Console.Write(folderfinder.SelectedPath);
}
```

The following code always returns "" for selectedpath. Anyone see what is wrong here? I have googled around and no one mentions having a problem with selectedpath returning no value.

Comment: Don't you think you should show it?  `folderfinder.ShowDialog()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show dialog ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
if (folderfinder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Console.Write(folderfinder.SelectedPath);
}
```